# The English Department

Tags: english, steganography, cryptic-clues, crosswords

After walking through the [computer science department](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46257/the-computer-science-department), the tour entered the English department. The interior was very spartan, and the only thing I could see was a pinboard with the following items:

[image: Crossword and clues]

[image: 3 rules and a student notice]

I tried to solve the crossword, but the clues were a puzzle in themselves.

What information does the crossword hide?

---

[PDF with crossword, clues, rules and notice](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gw794j4njzdmcun/English%20department.pdf?dl=0)

<sub>Again, this story is fictional.</sub>

Comment: just to be sure, is there any connection between the linked puzzle and this one?

Comment: @RichardRoe No. I would be burnt as a witch if it was. I might make an explicit metapuzzle later but for now they are just one-offs.

Comment: I'm very curious as to why 'steganography' is a tag...

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper For the bold and the italics and the underline, I thought it would be convention to include it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you used the wrong tag "cryptic clues". You should use "cryptic-crosswords".

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Thanks, but I believe cryptic crossword wasn't a tag at the time. I don't think it's worth bumping right now, since the tags are similar enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick to this crossword is that

> all the answers have to be entered as *sound* - each square is one *phoneme*, not letter. This also applies to clues - anagram clues mix up sounds, not letters, for instance.

The solution (or what I have so far):

> [image]
>  (I've used the [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English) to record answers.)

The highlighted squares spell out

> `foenimsnɒtgræfimsɪsðəki`, or:
>  **"Phonemes, not graphemes", is the key**.

Note that

> the clues only work in an Australian accent. For instance, 15-across is a container clue where "c**ore full**y" is supposed to sound like "awful". If, like me, you have an American accent, they would not sound similar.

Comment: Mostly correct, but beneath the *elementary* line things aren't quite right. Sorry for the accent reliance.

Comment: @boboquack: Yeah, that's what I figured. And hey, no need to apologize - I'm sure if I'd made a puzzle like this, it would be harder for you.

Comment: Will you finish the last part off as per the discussion on the Sphinx's Lair or do you want me to edit it in?

Answer (score 3):

### Partial answer

The "3 simple rules":

> 1. Bolded words are anagrams.
>  2. Italicised words require a vowel change.
>  3. Underlined words are spelled phonetically.

Thus, the clues become (changed words in italics):

> Across:
>  1 The answer to everything jumps at tea *for* two
>  4 Broad question *not closed*
>  7 Odour upset *trees*
>  8 Oral makeup made of deformed plastic
>  9 Form of binary addition *was* in an *image*
>  10 Antipodes held back the *lone* outsider
>  12 Recurrences looked like the patter with opposite points
>  14 *Cuts* were just ketchup
>  16 Lion's head *put into* the celebration up to a point
>  18 *Looped* tie was too *small* a fit
>  19 Primary school *was* basic
>  22 Motel was *not* out
>  23 *Certain* object *started* the Indian subcontinent
>  24 across, 24 *down* The article in two *ways*?
>  25 Precipitates *in* someone's *nose*
>  26 Bumpy *meat*
>
>  *Down*
>  1 Tooth inserts were the heart of the *pie*
>  2 Back *in* the days, it was his top eatery - *it* had delicious beverages
>  3 Egyptian pharaoh had a *strange* knock-knock
>  4 'A resistance unit? We're in trouble! *Oh* my!'
>  5 Writing implement *beheaded* 4 across
>  6 Smart *and* simple proof
>  7 Miss a large *bin*
>  11 Overstay looked like a confused *arty* R
>  13 He sat, ire seething within, *bemoaning* their mockeries
>  15 It was, *in* its core, fully terrible
>  17 Bulbs *broke* through the tiles
>  19 Texts within SA's library
>  20 Flour grinders had muddled moves
>  21 *Any* one looks like me in *ether*
>  24 *See* 24 across